# Prove that $S^{-1}: S(H) \rightarrow H$ exists

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $$S=I+T^*T: H \rightarrow H$$ where T is linear and bounded. Show that $$S^{-1} : S(H) \rightarrow H$$ exists.

I am working through Hilbert-Adjoint Operator exercises right now and i am stuck with this given above problem . I am unsure where to even start. Any hints/suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Are you are unsure where to even star also? Do you mean $I+T^{*}T$?

Comment: yes sorry, that is what I had but someone edited it and I didn't catch that.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is show that $\mathcal{N}(S)=\{0\}$, which follows because $Sx=0$ gives
$$
      0 = \langle Sx,x\rangle=\langle (I+T^{*}T)x,x\rangle=\|x\|^2+\|Tx\|^2 \\
              \implies x = 0.
$$
(Actually, though, you can show that $I+T^{\star}T$ is a bicontinuous bijection.)

Answer (score 0):

Recall that if for some bounded operator $B$  the following condition holds: $\|Bx\| \geq c\|x\|$ for some positive $c$ (for all $x\in H$) - then $\mathrm{Im} B$ is closed, $B$ is a bijection and $B^{-1}$ exists (and is bounded).

Now :
$$\|(I+T^*T)x\|^2 = \langle x+T^*Tx , x+T^*Tx \rangle = \|x\|^2 + \|T^*Tx\|^2 + 2\Re \langle x,T^*Tx\rangle $$

Since: $\|T^*Tx\|^2 \geq 0$ and $\Re \langle x,T^*Tx\rangle \geq 0$ (why?) then $\|(I+T^*T)x\| \geq c\|x\|$ and the condition holds.

Answer (score 0):

we know that $T$ is a bounded linear operator. So $T^*T$ is also a bounded linear operator since  composition of two bounded linear operator is a bounded linear operator.

I is the identity operator. Hence, it is bounded linear operator. So,$ S = I + T^*T$ is a bounded linear operator as sum of two bounded linear operator is a bounded linear operator.

Now, $S : H \rightarrow H$ is a bounded linear operator.

The identity operator $I : H \rightarrow H$ can be written as $S^{-1}S : H \rightarrow H $as $I = S^{-1}S$.

Let, $h \in H$. Then $I(h) = h$

This can be written as $S^{-1}S(h) = h$

Or, $S^{-1}(S(h)) = h$

As $h \in H$ and $S : H \rightarrow H$ is a bounded linear operator, $S(h) \in S(H)$. Let $S(h) = h_1 \in S(H)$

So, $S^{-1}(h_1) = h$ where $h \in H$ and $h_1 \in S(H)$

As $h$ is arbitrary, we can say that $S^{-1 }: S(H) \rightarrow H$ exists.